# React native Expo EAS build failed for android with path="" error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am building preview for android with an help of EAS and failed with below error. I didn’t have any issue with iOS as it works

MAIN error in android is as follow

```
[stderr] 
Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle' line: 10
27
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
28
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'ParrotProjectv2'.
29
[stderr] 
>
30
[stderr] 
path may not be null or empty string. path='null'
31
[stderr] 
* Try:
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following [GitHub page](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22584). It explains the same error you have + a solution which you can try.

My suggestion would be, go inside the android folder and execute the following command and try building again.

```
$  ./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually running the command eas build in the root folder and not the client folder. Once I ran in the client folder I did not get this pathing issue.